# How to insert an argument in a function through a loop and then call it that into the view in codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, html, codeigniter

Am trying to call a method from the model which requires an argument
but am stack the way am I have to pass an argument remember the value which I have to pass is the data from loop
I tried calling `get_feeds_comments($id)` method directly from  the view it works fine

But how can I really archive this if I first call the model method from the controller remember I have to pass an argument and then processed the data into the view and in the view am looping through the post from the database and then I need to assign a comment to its appropriate post

Guys am really stack please help

## This is the code for the model

```
<?php 
public function get_feeds_comments($id){
   $this->db->select('feeds_comment.comment, users.profile_img, users.last_name,users.first_name,feeds_comment.comment_date,feeds_comment.feedid');
   $this->db->from('feeds');
   $this->db->where('feeds.id',$id);
   $this->db->join('feeds_comment', 'feeds_comment.feedid = feeds.id');
   $this->db->join('users', 'users.id = feeds_comment.userid');
   $this->db->order_by('feeds_comment.comment_date');
   $result = $this->db->get();
   return $result->result();
 }
 ?>
```

## This is the code for the view

```
<?php
foreach($feeds_users as $single_data){
 ?>
 <div class="display_post">
    <div class="the_post">
        <?php echo $single_data->feed; ?>
        <hr>
     <?php print_r($comment); ?>
    </div>
 </div>
<?php
}
?>
```

## This is the code for the controller

```
<?php 
public function display_feeds(){
   $feeds_user_data  = $this->user_model->get_feeds_users();
   if(empty($feeds_user_data)){
      die();
     }else{
       foreach($feeds_user_data as $single_user_data){
        $display_user_id = $single_user_data;
       }
     }
   $data['test_comment_data'] = $this->user_model->display_comments($display_user_id->id);
}
?>
```

## And this is the model function get_feeds_users()

```
  public function get_feeds_users(){
  $this->db->select('*');
  $this->db->from('users');
  $this->db->join('feeds', 'feeds.userid = users.id');
  $this->db->order_by('feed_date',"DESC");
  $result = $this->db->get();
  return $result->result();
}
```

Comment: post your get_feeds_users model code too

Comment: Hey saty I have posted the get_feeds_users model, you can check it out. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From view call another controller that will take the $id for you model to be processed. The same controllers view will be rendered for you there and you will get processed data finally.